# How to diagram continuous user event maps in GUI?

Tags: uml, modeling, sysml

I'm trying to create a diagrams of user interactions. In many cases I have to take some arguments like: mousePosition.x or touchDown.duration etc, and pass it through some f(x) function to render different UI using these arguments as interface properties.

Let's take an example of basic slider interface. `[-----o-----]`

I want to diagram a simple behavior of manipulating slider's knob. My logic is as follows:

```
pre condition: mousePosition.x = knobPosition.x; knobPosition.x = n
event: mosuseDown
event: mouseMove.x
if knobPosition.xMin < mousePosition.x < knobPosition.xMax
   render: knobPosition.x = mousePosition.x
if ( mousePosition.x > knobPosition.xMax )
   render: knobPosition.x = knobPosition.xMax
if ( mousePosition.x < knobPosition.xMin )
   render: knobPosition.x = knobPosition.xMin
```

My first thought was to diagram this behavior through State Machine, although it becomes messy for more complex examples. Maybe there is some modeling language that was design to model these kind of behaviors?

Comment: I think that's more a design question. There are many ways how to implement this behavior. What are you targeting?

Comment: @qwerty_so My goal is to find a consistent approach to actually design these behaviors through diagrams. I'm aware that there are many ways to implement behaviors similar to what I've shown in Slider example. As a designer I want to be really clear what I've intended to design for a specific component. It is important for the product I'm building, because there are many UI elements that have non-standard behaviors. 
To sum up - I'm looking for a modeling language / diagram type, that would allow to model UI behaviors, especially when some user event values are mapped to UI appearance.

Comment: I'd guess that sequence diagrams offer the best choice for designing such behavior. It focuses on concrete coding. A state machine for the example would be not that expressive since you have only 2 or 3 states: idle, dragging and end of dragging.

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is a kind of decision tree. This can best be modeled using an activity diagram. Each if-statement is a decision symbol in the diagram.